# como hacer que un RadioButton aparezca seleccionado por defecto?

Tags: java, netbeans, radiobutton

Soy nueva en java y me preguntaba como puedo hacer para que un JRadioButton aparezca seleccionado por defecto, simplemente que de 2 uno ya venga seleccionado por defecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, recuerda que es importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisar [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como veo que usas Netbeans y estas trabajando con java swing entonces solo debes hacer.

```
//suponiendo que tu JRadioButton se llame radio1
radio1.setSelected(true);
```

Esa linea de código debe estar en el constructor de la clase después de `initComponents();`

```
public class OcultarBoton extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form OcultarBoton
     */
    public OcultarBoton() {
        initComponents();        
        radio1.setSelected(true);        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias @Joshin jejeje que facil era yo me tenia un mundo aqui jaajja

Comment: Si tienes varios componentes que quieres inicializar, puedes crear un método dentro de la clase y llamar después de ``initComponents();``

Answer (score 2):

Debes enviarle el true como segundo parametro, para seleccionarlo detras del texto del boton.

```
JRadioButton option1 = new JRadioButton("Texto", true);
```

Revisa la [documentaciòn](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JRadioButton.html#JRadioButton-java.lang.String-boolean-):

```
JRadioButton​(String text, boolean selected)
```

> Crea un botón de opción con el texto y el estado de selección
> especificados.

Comment: y eso donde lo ago en el contructor de la ventana donde esta el Jradiobutton? porque haciendolo alli me marca error cuando creo el objeto

Comment: Edita la pregunta y pon tu código, así puedo ser mas preciso..

Comment: es que el problema es que yo no tengo ningun codigo echo sobre estos botones, simplemente queria que me guiaran a como poner hacer que uno de estos saliera seleccionado por defecto, digamos esto lo cree desde la parte grafica de netbeans no lo hice a punta de codigo

Comment: entonces estoy en 0 y por eso te preguntaba que si ese objeto lo debo crear en el constructor de la ventana que tiene esos botones?

Comment: Ahi con la imagen que pusiste ya veo lo que usas, mas abajo Joshin te ha dado la solución!

Comment: gracias igualmente por tomarte el tiempo de leerme @KatiaSisHost

Comment: Igual era la respuesta inicial. Buen día